# Display data from an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

In index.php page i have a script that fetches data from demo.php and displays the result in a div.

```
<div class="leftbox">
    <?php
        echo "<div id='proddisplay'>";
        echo "</div>";
    ?>
</div>

var onSubmit = function(e) {
    var txtbox = $('#txt').val();
    var hiddenTxt = $('#hidden').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'demo.php',
        data: {
            txt: txtbox,
            hidden: hiddenTxt
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(returndata) {
            $('#proddisplay').html(returndata);
            console.log(returndata);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
        }
    });
};
```

in demo.php script i get the result from

```
print_r($result);
```

the result that i get in the div is

```
Array ( [0] => 1st value [1] => 2nd value [2] => 3rd value [3] => 4th value )
```

I wish to get individial data from this array so that i can use each data seperately and wherever i want in the index.php page, but i am not able to do so. can anyone tell how can i fetch individual values from array for index page

P.S: 
i have an option to display the format in demo page in the form of result[0] and so on for every index value and call it as it is in the index page but that bounds me with the css. I wish to use any css in index page and just call the values in index page.

I tried using result[0] in index page but it displayed no result i tried assigning the values of an array to a variable and then call these variables to index page but that also didn't displayed any result

Comment: And your problem is? You've not asked any questions. Also you shouldn't use `<?` short tags, not every server supports them. Use `<?php` always.

Comment: @Styphon i wish to use values from the array individually on index page

Comment: OK, so why haven't you googled this? One quick google will tell you that you can access them using `$result[0]` for the first value, or `$result[1]` for the second.

Comment: @Styphon i can definatley use this and display value but when i use this in demo page then only i get the result. one way is that i display the o/p format in demo page and call that in index page that will give me the desired o/p but it keeps a restriction on design. i wish to design my index page in any form and just use the value from array. if i write $result[1] in the index page, i get no result

Comment: Right, you didn't explain that properly. I understand now. I'll add an answer that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to loop through values in an array is to use `foreach`.

## foreach

```
foreach($result as $value){
    print($value);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp

Comment: data is not getting displayed. i am getting blank value

Answer (score 0):

Either access each value individually - for example `$result[0]`.  Or if you want to loop over the entire array you can use `foreach`

Example:

```
foreach($result as $val){
   //do something with $val
}
```

[PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: didn't got any result

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign values of indexes to variables like below:

```
$first_value = $result[0];
$second_value = $result[1];
$third_value = $result[2];
$fourth_value = $result[3];
```

and so on in same sequence.

Comment: i am not able to display data in this form

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Ajax to get the data, you need to pass the array back as a JSON string. Add another parameter, `dataType: 'JSON'` to your Ajax call, this tells jQuery you're expecting a JSON string as a response and it'll automatically convert the JSON into an array for you when passing the result to the success function.

Then in your `data.php` value you need to run `echo json_encode($result);` to pass result back to the Ajax success function as a JSON string. jQuery converts it back from a JSON string to an array for us (that's why we add the `dataType`). Then in your Ajax success function you `console.log(resultdata.0)` you'll get value1, and `console.log(resultdata.1)` will give you value2.

Comment: can u plz tel dis in code form, i am not able to apply it properly

Answer (score 0):

convert your array to json

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

in your script

```
var onSubmit = function(e) {
  var txtbox = $('#txt').val();
  var hiddenTxt = $('#hidden').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'test2.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      txt: txtbox,
      hidden: hiddenTxt
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(returndata) {
         $('#first').html(returndata[0]);
          $('#second').html(returndata[1]);
           $('#third').html(returndata[2]);
            $('#fourth').html(returndata[3]);
         console.log(returndata[0]);
    },
    error: function() { 
      console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
    }
  });
};
```

first,second,third,fourth will be the id of the div or the area where you wish to display the result